# Can I create a totally transparent UIView that receives touches?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, alpha, uitouch

I want to create a totally transparent UIView overlay (and it has subviews) to receives touches. I could set the alpha to a low value (like 0.02) to get an approximate effect.

But I wonder is it possible for a `alpha == 0` UIView to receives touches, through other UIView configs?

Comment: why you not using UIButton with costume style..?

Comment: @NitinGohel I didn't know that. Not sure if it fits my problem.

Comment: see if u are want to touch event of your Uivew then it bit code for it with event, Gesture etc but using Button u can access it's IBAction and get click event also and if button's style is custome then no need to set alpha also..Bit easy insted of using UIView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by overriding the `hitTest:withEvent:` method in the class of your fully transparent view, like:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return self;
}
```

The implementation of `hitTest:withEvent:` doesn't have to be that simple, of course.  The point is that you can cause even a fully transparent view to be touchable as long as *something* returns that view from `hitTest:withEvent:`.

Do note, however, that screwing around with `hitTest:withEvent:` is an easy way to create some very weird bugs.  Use this method with caution.

Comment: Yes, messing around with that method may be risky. What about overwriting `drawRect:` ? Overwriting that is very well documented. It could, controlled by some custom flag, either just call `[super drawRect:...];` to have the view drawn in a regular way with all its properties etc or simply don't do anything in the invisible-but-tuchable state that @smilingpoplar would invent.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I tried overwriting `drawRect:` with an empty body. The subviews still show.

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do this is to set the background colour:

```
UIView *view = ...;
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to this to hook up a selector to respond to tapping.

Comment: But the UIView has some subviews. Setting its backgroundColor can't hide those subviews.